# Exception after crash during recovery in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I tried to recover from a sudden shutdown of Mongo, but I'm experiencing some problems. Here is the log file:

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=19996 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=Vault
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.3, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] git version: f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", nohttpinterface: "true" }
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] recover begin
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] recover lsn: 3778163987
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] recover /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] dbexception during recovery: 13537 journal file header invalid. This could indicate corruption in a journal file, or perhaps a crash where sectors in file header were in flight written out of order at time of crash (unlikely but possible).
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13537 journal file header invalid. This could indicate corruption in a journal file, or perhaps a crash where sectors in file header were in flight written out of order at time of crash (unlikely but possible)., terminating
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 dbexit:
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Apr 25 01:09:17 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log file, you are using MongoDB version v2.2.3. This version is not officially supported by MongoDB, so I'd recommend you plan to upgrade to a newer version. The latest stable version, MongoDB 4.0.9.

As per the log message, the journal file j._0 in /var/lib/mongodb/journal/ folder is corrupted.

Try, removing the j._0 file and do the recovery process.

Disclaimer: you may lose some data that present in the journal file.